# How may I get more values of a variable than my linspace while solving ODE in Python? (EDIT)

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, ode

To check some of my results more easily I used an Excel sheet to make a few diagrams. However, I noticed something really awkward.

**EDIT :**

So let present the problem in another way, I found something that represent what I don't understand in my code.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint

A = []


def F(y, z):
    global A
    a = y[0]
    b = y[1]

    A.append(a)

    return [a, b]


y0 = [1, 1]
z = np.linspace(0, 1, 101)
y = odeint(F, y0, z)
print(len(z), len(A))
```

The question is why the length of z and A are different (e.g. 101 and 55)?

For me ,during the solving, `a` should vary `len(z)` times and so `A`. So it looks like the linspace is not doing anything on the solving of the equations. Or perhaps I haven't understood the usage of linspace in Python.

Comment: I don't think nobody will be able to help you with a code like that, take a look at this: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @olinox14 thank you for your help. At least I am looking if any error like that is possible. Maybe someone else has already encountered this kind of error.

Comment: Can you simplify your code down to a toy example that still shows the same behaviour? Then at least we can try it out to see what is happening. And, of course, in the process of doing that, it is entirely possible that you will find the problem yourself.

Comment: @BoarGules well I have more than two thousand lines of code because I am performing multiple thermodynamics calculations depending on various models and I don't want to share my whole code. I can't do less than oversimplifying it. All I can say is that all the variables inside the function ODE have more values than the linspace.

Comment: @BoarGules I edited my code with something that imitates my problem. And actually is probably not supposed to be one but I don't understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution via odeint uses an implicit linear multi-step method with adaptive internal time stepping. This is implemented via a PECE predictor-corrector scheme. The E there stands for "evaluation". Which means that in each internal integration step, the ODE function is called twice. You might get less internal steps than the input time list has entries, the output array is interpolated from the internal time steps, so that you can have multiple output values per internal step. But the other extreme is also possible, that to reach the requested tolerances the internal step size is so small that one output time step requires multiple internal steps.

If the problem were more stiff, there would be even more calls, periodically for the numerical approximation of the Jacobian, and possibly multiple calls per step of the Newton-like corrector step or just multiple simple correction steps, which is then called PE(CE)<sup>d</sup>.

---

To compare with, look at the explicit RK4 method. There you have 4 evaluations of the ODE function per time step. The Dormand-Prince method of ode45 has 6+1 evaluations per time step, however there the internal time steps need not correspond to the time sample list passed to the method, the requested output samples are interpolated from the internal steps.

Comment: Interesting to know. I've never seen that using Matlab. In my original problematic I get 111 values for a linspace of 100. Do you know how may I find the values calculated with the second evaluation so that I can remove them? It would be nice if it could be kinda automatic.

Comment: Why do you want that? The output `y` corresponds exactly to the times `z`, no further processing needed.

Comment: well actually it does not. If I make a print of one of my variable inside my function I get extra values. I mean I use a variable I don't need to record in a vector to perform the calculations. Now if I try to add this variable in a vector like all others, the incrementation is not done correctly (the values are not the same as those I get when I just make a print...). So I'm kinda lost

Comment: This I did not grok. I'm guessing that you could have the conceptual problem that assigning arrays is actually only copying the address to the array object, not making an independent copy of the contents. Use the `.copy()` method to generate this independent copy.